# How to programmatically layout days in a calendar in a way that matches the month and day of the week?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can I do this?

I'm sure this has been done before. I've checked a couple of projects on github, such as calendar master, but they are all more complicated than what I need.

**Oct 2013**

S  M  T  W  T  F  S

30 **1 2 3 4 5 6**

**7 8 9 10 11 12 13**

**14 15 16 17 18 19 20**

**21 22 23 24 25 26 27**

**28 29 30 31** 1 2 3

Is there a best approach to do this? To layout days in a way that will match the day of the week for that month?

This will be made in a tableview, but I'm not looking for code, just the logic behind it. Unless there's a really good solution out there already.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic could be something like this (pseudo code):

```
get the weekday of the first day of the month in question
determine the number of days of the previous month
fill the first line 
   with leading final days of previous month, if any
   the remaining days for the first week of the month in question
fill all other lines
fill the rest of the last line 
   with the first days of the following month, if any space left
```